# verticalResize property not working on <apex:emailPublisher

Tags: publisher-action

Since spring '14 release there is a new property available to let users resize the vertical space of a custom publisher action.

You can create a visual force page and add the following code to it and then use that page as a publisher action on the case feed layout.

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" >
    <apex:emailPublisher entityId="{!case.id}"
       width="100%"
       fromVisibility="selectable"
       subjectVisibility="readOnly"
       subject="Re: {!case.subject}"
       expandableHeader="true"
       enableQuickText="true"
       verticalResize="true"
       showTemplates="true"
       emailbodyFormat="HTML"
       toAddresses="{!case.contact.email}"
       emailBody=""/>
</apex:page>
```

Now i tried already a lot to get that resize working but i don't succeed. I tried in Safari, Chrome and FireFox without success. Now on the developer.force blog there is a post about that and in the screenshot you clearly see an option to resize like below
[image]

Source of this image [enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AlzeIAC)

This is what i have in my screens
[image]

Anybody an idea why i don't have that resize thingy? api version of my page is 33 so should be ok